# Пагинация с использованием MultipleObjectMixin в Django ( AttributeError: object has no attribute 'object_list' )

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать пагинацию с помощью MultipleObjectMixin. Но вылетает:

> 'ListingCakeView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

```
class ListingCakeView(MultipleObjectMixin,TemplateResponseMixin, View):

paginate_by = 1
model = CakeModel
template_name = 'list_cakes.html'

def post(self,request, context, **kwargs):
   return render_to_response(request, context)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListingCakeView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    paginator, page, cakes, is_paginate = self.paginate_queryset(self.get_queryset() ,
                                                                 self.paginate_by)
    context['page'] = page      
    return context

def get(self, request, **kwargs):    
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(**kwargs), **kwargs)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую посмотреть исходный код класса [BaseListView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L154) в django. Этот класс, как и ваш `ListingCakeView` наследуется от классов `MultipleObjectMixin` и `View`.
В начале метода `get` указана строка в которой инициализируется `object_list`

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```